# Bridging users together that have the same app installed from their contacts list

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I'm trying to make an Android app where I use a users' ContactsContract database to link the user to another user in there contacts list, who also happens to have this specific app downloaded. But I'm having trouble visualizing best practices to go about achieving this functionality?

Example: John downloaded the app "FirstApp". He has someone in his contacts list, Bob, who also downloaded the app "FirstApp". When John clicks a button in the app, it'll open his contacts list, but only Bob should be available because he's the only one with "FirstApp" installed.

Is this sort of concept built-in already? I'm not seeing it in the Android doc's. Does it involve having to build your own ContentProvider of some sort?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, 
Have you found an answer to your question ?
I'm looking for the same kind of thing.
Something that WhatsApp implements well for example... In WhatsApp you only see your contacts who have WhatsApp installed.

Thanks for any update.

Comment: Hi Mario, the solution that I went with was connecting users by their phone numbers in the back-end. This would require you having the permission to get their phone number when they download the app. Phone numbers are fairly unique in my opinion. E.g. If there's a phone number in your app's database that isn't the current user's phone number, but is the phone number of someone in that user's contacts list, then there's the connection. Only display the name attached to that phone number for the user. Hope this helped

Comment: Ok. This helps :). I was searching for a solution to have a "standalone" application, but I guess I'll have to host a shared database. 
Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a built in feature to match that up.

The only way i can figure out is for you to grab the whole list of the user's contacts and match it against your DB (and sync up every time the user adds a new contact).

Just make sure the user is VERY aware that you intend to use his contact list as handling this on the wrong way could have your app flagged... fast.

Comment: Thanks jirungaray! Guess I'll have to do it that way

Answer (score 1):

Send all the user contacts from the phone to server, in server verify each contact against your DB, if match is found push matched contact in new array finally send the resultant array to client.

Answer (score 0):

Access users contacts, look up with your registered users, if any registered user matches, notify the user.

There's no built in concept I guess.

Comment: Hi Gauraw, thanks for the suggestion, same as jirungaray's so that's what I'll be doing.